# Highest value of sequence for each booking

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I need to retrieve all the values of Booking_ID but with their highest individual respective 'Sequence' values. How can I do this?

[image: Pic]

So the result should be something like this :

```
BookingID Destination    Destination
1010      199591             1 <--- I need only this row
1011      188061             1 <--- I need only this row
1012      118628             1 <--- this should not be here
1012      188061             2 <--- this should not be here
1012      169420             3 <--- I need only this row
1013      179555             1 <--- I need only this row
1014      179037             1 <--- I need only this row
1015      499172             1 <--- I need only this row
1016      189558             1 <--- I need only this row
1017      018953             1 <--- I need only this row
1018      169420             1 <--- I need only this row
1019      169420             1 <--- I need only this row
1020      098585             1 <--- This should not be here
1020      098269             2 <--- I need only this row
1021      499172             1 <--- I need only this row
```

Comment: If the other answers are too slow (for large tables), see [Groupwise max](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select b1.*
  from booking b1 
 where not exists ( select 1 
                      from booking b2
                     where b2.id       = b1.id 
                       and b2.sequence > b1.sequence
                  )
```

Comment: May I know what does :
select b1.* 
and
select 1 from booking b2 means?

Comment: b1 is just an alias and 1 is just anything.  Exists is just checking for anything.  If this is the answer to your question you can indicate so by clicking the check.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for the Maximum value for Sequence for each Booking_ID you could write some SQL similar to that below:

```
SELECT Booking_ID,MAX(Sequence) FROM  MyTable GROUP BY Booking_ID;
```

Where MyTable is the name of the table in your database.

I have created a sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42af5c/1/0).